# Unable to load library for dependecy project in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am migrating a big project that contains more than 5 dependency libraries from `Eclipse` to `Android Studio`.

> I ain't able to run compile
>   `'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'` if I put
>   `com.android.library` but able to run by setting it to
>   `com.andriod.application`.

Please Help

[here is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XA1iO.png)

Comment: Try putting this in your top-level gradle file. 
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

Answer (score 0):

Your gradle file starts like so:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
```

and in "dependencies" you place your dependency:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.3.0'
}
```